# convert sql subquery with multiple joins to linq

Tags: sql, linq, subquery

I'm having trouble working in my subselect into LINQ.  Here is the SQL followed by the LINQ.  The SQL Query runs fine.  The problem is incorporating the subquery.  Any assistance would be appreciated:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
   cic.CommitmentItemCategoryName + '( ' + cicType.CommitmentItemCategoryTypeName + ' )' AS displayCategory
   , 'CategoryType_' + CAST(cic.CommitmentItemCategoryID AS VARCHAR(10)) AS displayCategoryID
   , ISNULL(vwPAD.DollarsAllocated, 0) AS DisplayDollarsAllocated
   ,cic.CommitmentItemCategoryID
FROM
   tblCommitmentItemCategory cic
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
   tblCommitmentItemCategoryType cicType ON cic.CommitmentItemCategoryTypeID = cicType.CommitmentItemCategoryTypeID
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
   tblAccountDirectToCommitmentItemCategory adToCIC ON adToCIC.CommitmentItemCategoryID IN (SELECT CommitmentItemCategoryID FROM tblCommitmentItemCategory)
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
   vw_ParentAccountDollarsAllocatedByCommitmentItemCategory vwPAD ON  vwPAD.FiscalYear = 2015 
                  AND cic.CommitmentItemCategoryID = vwPAD.CommitmentItemCategoryID
                  AND vwPAD.AccountDirectParentID = 19
WHERE 
    adToCIC.AccountDirectParentID = 19
ORDER BY
    displayCategory

var queryInner = from cic in MyContext.tblCommitmentItemCategory
                                 select new
                                 {
                                     cic.CommitmentItemCategoryID
                                 };

                var queryDollars = (from cic in MyContext.tblCommitmentItemCategory
                                   join cicType in MyContext.tblCommitmentItemCategoryType
                                   on cic.CommitmentItemCategoryTypeID equals cicType.CommitmentItemCategoryTypeID
                                   into t2
                                   from cicType in t2.DefaultIfEmpty()

                                   join adToCIC in MyContext.tblAccountDirectToCommitmentItemCategory
 //What goes here?
                                   on ...
                                  // on cic.CommitmentItemCategoryID equals     adToCIC.CommitmentItemCategoryID
                                   into t3
                                   from adToCIC in t3.DefaultIfEmpty()

                                   join vw in MyContext.vw_ParentAccountDollarsAllocatedByCommitmentItemCategory
                                   on new { FiscalYear = currentFiscalYear, CommitmentItemCategory = cic.CommitmentItemCategoryID, ParentAccountID = currentParentAccountID } 
                                    equals new { FiscalYear = vw.FiscalYear, CommitmentItemCategory = vw.CommitmentItemCategoryID, ParentAccountID = vw.AccountDirectParentID }
                                   into t
                                   from vw in t.DefaultIfEmpty()

                                   where adToCIC.AccountDirectParentID == currentParentAccountID

                                   let displayCategory = cic.CommitmentItemCategoryName + " ( " + cicType.CommitmentItemCategoryTypeName + " )"

                                   // Called CategoryType but it's actually the ID below

                                   let displayCategoryTypeID = "CategoryType_" + cic.CommitmentItemCategoryID.ToString()
                                   //let displayCategoryTypeID = "CategoryType!" + cic.CommitmentItemCategoryID + "_" + adToCIC.AccountDirectToCommitmentItemCategoryID.ToString()
                                   let displayDollarsAllocated = vw.DollarsAllocated == null ? 0 : vw.DollarsAllocated

                                   orderby cic.CommitmentItemCategoryName
                                   select new
                                   {
                                       displayCategory,
                                       displayCategoryTypeID,
                                       cic.CommitmentItemCategoryID,
                                       displayDollarsAllocated
                                   }).Distinct();
```

Comment: From my experinece with `linq` left joins are somehow hard to configure. Why not create a function and make use it in `linq`?

Answer (score 0):

Can you convert `queryInner` to a join? Then use that result in the larger query:

```
var queryInner = 
    from atcic in MyContext.tblAccountDirectToCommitmentItemCategory
    join cic in MyContext.tblCommitmentItemCategory on atcic.CommitmentItemCategoryID equals cic.CommitmentItemCategoryID
    select atcic;
```

And in the big query:

```
join adToCIC in queryInner into t3
    from adToCIC in t3.DefaultIfEmpty()
```